# Blackberry push notification - push server sample app missing

Tags: blackberry, notifications, push

We tried to implement the push notification in blackberry. We followed the steps provided in BB developer guide.

We installed the push SDK in our system. once the SDK is installed, we checked whether the tomcat is running ... It was running fine. But, we could not find the sample push server app. (war file is missing in the webapps folder of tomcat).

Are we missing anything or should we install the push server sample app seperately from elsewhere ?

Any pointers where the steps for configuring a push server and a push client app (in device) would be very much helpful ....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[php Server side code reference](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/BB-BIS-push-PHP-server-works-on-push-all-but-not-on-specified/td-p/1173427)

This is very helpful for the server side code.